# Rollup does not reslove packages from custom module folder?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I am trying to bundle an web application that written with ES6 module system & using rollup from command line with custom modules folder that I want use it as root modules directory to be resolved. Then I downloaded some packages to that custom folder with `yarn add --modules-folder <custom folder path>`. Now When I am using this command `rollup -w -i App.js -o bundle.js -p '<modules path>/@rollup/plugin-babel={presets:["<modules path>/babel-preset-solid"]}' -p '<modules path>/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve={extensions:[".js"],customResolveOptions:{moduleDirectory:"<modules path>"}}'` I am getting this error `(node:13672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot load plugin "<modules path>/@rollup/plugin-babel": Cannot find module '<modules path>/@rollup/plugin-babel'` But I am pretty sure that all packages are in custom moduels folder path. But strangely when do same process and download packages to custom location with `node_modules` folder in it, It works fine. So what is the problem? What am I missing here?

Comment: There's probably a plug-in out there for this but you should be aware that by using a custom directory for your dependencies you're going to break the assumptions of many tools that rely on conventions

Comment: Yes you are right. But there are some questions that I don't have answer for those. 1. Why using any custom folder name does not work except for node_modules folder name in <modules path> location in command string? 2. What is the role of node-module-resolve plugin in this process? Is it not the job of the node-module-resolve plugin to do package resolution in compile time?

Comment: Are talking about [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-node-resolve)? Package module resolution is indeed what those plugins are for.

Comment: I think the issue is you're mixing up the configuration for @rollup/plugin-node-resolve and rollup-plugin-node-resolve which are distinct plugins.  Looking at the docs for the former, it has a "moduleDirectories" (note the plural and no bounding object).  Perhaps you could try that.

Comment: [edit: I tried that newer syntax and it appears to be a documentation bug! They preserved the old syntax in the current module.  Different versions of the README are out there apparently!]